# License NSIS code posted on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Under which license is the code published by the NSIS Team on Stack Overflow released? Stack Overflow assigns the

```
CC BY-SA
```

license by default ([as indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). Does this also apply to NSIS code?

Comment: So practically one should reuse the code without knowing exactly the license assigned by whoever publishes it? As I indicated, Stack Overflow automatically assigns the CC BY-SA license without even giving the possibility to modify it. So in fact a developer is obliged to publish his code in posts only with that license. Note, in case you don't know, that most NSIS code is released under the zlib/libpng license.

Comment: ***All*** "user contributions [are] licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)." If that's about NSIS, SQL, Javascript, or the best way to cook bacon in an air fryer, it still applies. *Who* (from a user perspective) publishes it and *what* it's about *does not matter*. This is true for *all* sites in the network, not just [so].

Comment: The NSIS Team (whatever it is) is not to be confused the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System). Or is it?

Comment: "NSIS Team" may refer to a single person (developer). What is the Stack Overflow user profile?

Answer (score 11):

To expand on my comment (and repeat it): ***All*** "user contributions [are] licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)."

What that content is about, and what user posted that content, *do not matter*. If someone from the "NSIS team" posts about NSIS, be that as an answer, question, comment, etc., it is licensed under CC BY-SA. Who the individual works for *doesn't matter*.

As such it is *vitally important* that someone who is providing content *copied* from elsewhere is allowed to redistribute it (under CC BY-SA). If, for example, the "NSIS team" is using content from an internal resource that has a more strict licence on it, *if* they reposted it here then that licence would effectively no longer apply. (I am *not a lawyer*, so consult a real lawyer for real legal advice.) In such an event that someone were to post content that they weren't allowed to (re)licence under CC BY-SA, then the copyright owner would need to contact Stack Overflow.

Note, as well, that this applies to *all* sites in the Network, not just Stack Overflow. If you're on Super User, Stack Exchange, [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), etc., they all apply the CC BY-SA licence to user contributions.

From the initially linked CC BY-SA page:

> ### What is the license for the content I post?
>
> As noted in the Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) and in the footer of every page, all publicly accessible user contributions are licensed under [Creative Commons > Attribution-ShareAlike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license as follows:
>
> - Content contributed before 2011-04-08 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).
> - Content contributed from 2011-04-08 up to but not including 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
> - Content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).
>
> The license applicable for each Question and Answer revision is available on the [post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316). See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates) for more information.
>
> Please read the terms of service [[Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service)] and the full legal text of the license carefully for more details on how your content can be used and for how you can use publicly accessible content contributed to the site by other users.

Comment: Note that copyright holders are allowed to dual license, in which case licensees may pick under which license they use the code. This is mainly relevant if you want to drop restrictions imposed by CC BY SA, in which case you can license code under things like MIT, CC0, WTFPL, etc., but can also be relevant for licenses with entirely different properties. CC BY SA is particularly problematic because of the SA requirement, which can preclude inclusion into projects under incompatible licenses.